# Like a url with the facebook-ios-sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I know it's possible to like a page from the Facebook SDK for iOS, but is there a way to have a url/link and to like that url/link?

I've implemented Facebook SSO in the application and would like to use the login for the user to like a URL.

The thing I'm working on now is a blog-like view that will show posts from a certain site, and I would also like to be able to like that blog post, since I have the URL from the specific blog-post.

So if I would like to implement a like button on every blog post in the app, is there a way to do this through the Facebook iOS SDK?

And if not, which is the best workaround that will not require the user to log in again?
I'm talking about a web-view like solution?

Comment: what version of sdk do you use?

Comment: Right now I'm using sdk version 2 of the facebook sdk for iOS. And the application should be compaitble with at least with iOS 4.1.